# How to access data from txt or pdf file into java code for condition checking

Tags: java

```
 this is   x.txt 
 file     
    12=aa
    1234=ytuu
    157=lkjh

    // above is the sample of data(from 7700 similiar lines in actual file) in a txt file . i want to use that data for condition checking in my java code like 

    if (n==12){
     System.out.println("aa");}
    else
    if (n==1234){
     System.out.println("ytuu");}
```

is there any way to access these data rather than typing all the lines into my code.if so , how ?
    i am a beginner so please help me with this one.

Comment: Read and parse the file in your code. There are numerous ways to do this.

Comment: I would say that working with *.properties file type would help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do, but if you try to read some kind of configuration, you could read the file line per line, use a properties file or even read an xml with jaxb (that would propably be overkill for just a few lines  though)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to read a properties file you should do it like this

```
  Properties properties = new Properties();
  FileReader reader = new FileReader(new File("your_file.txt"));
  properties.load(reader);
  reader.close();
  System.out.print(properties.getProperty("12"));
```

Assuming that your file is only this kind of key=value pairs.

Comment: #Zpetkov   is it same for the files with large number of lines as mentioned above?

Comment: You are concerned about the memory buffer used for the file reading? As I look into the source code of properties.load() it uses 8 KB buffer. Consult the properties javadoc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html